# Is there any good browser plugin or tool to quickly identify any security issues of a web site?

Tags: security-testing

I'm working on a web project and need to give a quick update on how the security of the web site.
So is there any tool or browser plugin to do a quick scan for my web project and get an analysis report.

Answer (score 4):

Yes for a few things but overall really I feel the answer is no single tool for what you seek.

Reviewing security is a manual process because it is is a multi-faceted process.  It will frequently involve using various tools but there is not an overarching tool you can use to simply run a security report that I am aware of.

Also, if such a tool exists it will be of limited use as a broswer plugin, given that most of the security issues require analysis on the backend - and for that, there are security scan tools - but even these do not fully suffice because intent will not be clear just from the static code analysis.

A browser tool could report on:

- If HTTPS is being used
- Any hidden code in the HTML not displayed
- XSS (Cross Site Scripting)
- JavaScript vulnerabilities

Server side tools can report on:

- SQL injection
- JavaScript vulnerabilities
- Username/password storage in code (bad!)
- Large scale SQL updates
- Security in the application code
- Calls to other services
- Many other security concerns

Above are not comprehensive lists for security testing.
For that buy a security testing book and spend $20 to earn $80000

Also, from:
https://cwatch.comodo.com/blog/website-security/top-10-vulnerability-assessment-scanning-tools/ (March 2018)

Top 10 Vulnerability Assessment Scanning Tools

- Comodo HackerProof
- OpenVAS
- Nexpose Community
- Nikto
- Tripwire IP360
- Wireshark
- Aircrack
- Nessus Professional
- Retina CS Community
- Microsoft Baseline Security Analyzer (MBSA)

Comment: Thanks Michael, That ring the bell on me.

Comment: See also https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/607/8992

Comment: See also https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/18202/8992

Comment: Dont forget the famous OWASP ZAP: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project